# Converting GDI+ PixelFormat to WPF PixelFormat

Tags: wpf, gdi+

What is the best way to get the [System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.aspx) value equivalent to a [System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *a way* of converting, so lets start here and see if someone can top this horrendeous contraption. They map well to eachother, so writing the switch cases should be fairly easy.

```
private static System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat ConvertPixelFormat(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat sourceFormat)
{
    switch (sourceFormat)
    {
        case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
            return PixelFormats.Bgr24;

        case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
            return PixelFormats.Bgra32;

        case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
            return PixelFormats.Bgr32;

        // .. as many as you need...
    }
    return new System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something like that. It's just tricky to be sure that all similarly named formats are actually perfectly equivalent.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555` doesn't seem to have an equivalent if I haven't missed something. But that format seems rather obscure anyway (5 bits RGB each + 1 bit alpha).

Comment: If some are not supported, perhaps the return value should be an optional/nullable. The caller would have to decide whether to throw or do something else if there was no corresponding format found.