# TypeConverter to convert byte[] to Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, bitmap, typeconverter

I have this:

```
byte[] ar = new byte[ArrayAnsammlung[DurchLaeufer].Length];
ArrayAnsammlung[DurchLaeufer].CopyTo(ar, 0);
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
try
{
    bild = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(ar);
}
catch (Exception ddd)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ddd.ToString());
}
```

ar contains bitmap data, ie Blue-Green-Red-Alpha-Blue....

I am trying to convert it into the Bitmap bild. This is what the console shows:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
System.ArgumentException: Invalid Parameter.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
   at SK.MainWindow.thread() in MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 523.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: **[Posting this here for anyone viewing this later]** These classes expect a full image file, with a header. If your data is bare pixel bytes, you _can't_ solve this problem: you're lacking all header information, like image colour format and image dimensions. Once you do have that, you can simply make a new Bitmap of those specifications, open up its underlying data using `LockBits`, and copy your data inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static Bitmap BytesToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Invalid Parameter.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at SK.MainWindow.BytesToBitmap(Byte[] byteArray) in MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 571.

Comment: previously I have byte[] ar = new byte[ArrayAnsammlung[DurchLaeufer].Length];  ArrayAnsammlung[DurchLaeufer].CopyTo(ar, 0); so it should be byte[]

Comment: Yes it is a byte array but the content may be incorrect ! Are you sure about the format of this byte array to be a true RGB format ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12143/discussion-between-richart-bremer-and-kamran-amini)

Comment: Can you proceed here, please. This post may be useful for the others ;)

Comment: Alright I found the byte array to be Bgr32 and bild needs Format24bppRgb. How do you convert an Bgr32 byte array to an Format24bppRgb byte array?

Comment: Great, good news. Try to read these links, you may find something.[Image has wrong Image.PixelFormat on Windows 7, not on XP](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/winforms/thread/c626a478-e5ef-4a5e-9a73-599b3b7a6ecc) and [Converting GDI+ PixelFormat to WPF PixelFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106505/converting-gdi-pixelformat-to-wpf-pixelformat)

Comment: I don't see in how far those two links are helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the `TypeConverter` isn't working, but you can achieve this just as easily with the `Bitmap` class's Stream constructor:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ar)
var bild = new Bitmap(memoryStream);
```

Note that as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx), the `memoryStream` has to stay alive for the lifetime of the object.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Invalid Parameter.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
   at SK.MainWindow.thread() ......

Comment: I'm guessing, then, that your byte[] isn't a valid Bitmap.

Comment: Alright I found the byte array to be Bgr32 and bild needs Format24bppRgb. How do you convert an Bgr32 byte array to an Format24bppRgb byte array?